# request get stuck from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i wrote some code in nodejs. it's about to get html from website.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var path = require('path');'
var fs = require('fs');
var num = 0;
var arc = '';
for(var i=0; i < 20000; i++) {
    num++;
    var requrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/'+ num + '.html';
    request(requrl, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         console.log(body);    //get body
      }
    })
}
```

i just sent request to get html from 1.html to 20000.html

it starts okay, but it soon get stuck in about 1100.html

the console doesn't throw any error or exceptions.

it just stuck there, any solutions?

Comment: Does the process finish running (1100.html being the last one printed) or does the process really hang? Also, perhaps you can add an `else` to that `if` and put another `console.log()` in there to see if any requests come back with an error?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you loop through 20000 files and use the request method.  Maybe an alternative is to use a read stream with promises?