# nodejs http request stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in coding.

I want to scrape a lot of webpages, so there is my code.
The first one takes 2 arguments, host and paths. 
It will call the second function 'getXml' by forEach, and give it host and path to scrape the webpages one by one.

It usually works, and tell me error message when failing to get the webpage. But sometimes it won't show any error and the program just stuck there. I add two console.log in my second code to see what happens,
    console.log('chunk done');
    console.log('http end');
When the program stucks again.
the message on command line is

```
chunk done
chunk done
chunk done
http end
scrape webpage done(succeed to scrape a webpage)
chunk done
chunk done
http end
scrape webpage done (succeed to scape a webpage)
chunk done
chunk done
chunk done
(somethimes it stucks here, and no message shows, it just don't move on)
```

I don't know what's going on here and how to fix it.
It's similar this quesion: 
[request get stuck from nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103275/request-get-stuck-from-nodejs)

Is it because the internet connection(untable sometimes)? If it is, how to deal with this situation?

Would somebody give me some help and advise? I will be very appreciate for that. Thank you.

My node version is v7.2.0

And I also use the following modules.

"babel-polyfill": "6.16.0", "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0", "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0", "babel-register": "6.18.0"

First code:

```
import {getXml} from './getXml.js';
import fs from 'fs';

export function scrape(host, paths) {    
  let ready = Promise.resolve(null);

  paths.forEach((path, index) => {
    ready = ready.then(() => {
      return getXml(host, path);
    }).then((xml) => {
      // do something with the xml
      // I use fs.writeFileSync to save the xml
      console.log('scrape', host + path, 'done');
    }, (errMessage) => {
      // do somthing if there is error
      // I use fs.appendFileSync to save the err messages
      console.log('scrape failed:', errMessage);
    });
  });
};
```

Second code:

```
import http from 'http';

export function getXml(host, path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let option = {
      "host": host,
      "path": path
    };

    http.get(option, (res) => {
      let xml = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        xml += chunk;
        console.log('chunk done');
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(xml);
        console.log('http end');
      });
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      let errMessage = host + path;
      reject(errMessage);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add setTimeout() to abort the request after 10 secs, and reject the Promise at the same time. Don't know if it's useful or not.

Second code:

```
import http from 'http';

export function getHttpXml(host, path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let option = {
      'host': host,
      'path': path
    };
    let errMessage = host + path;

    // add setTimeout() here
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      req.abort();
      reject(errMessage);
    }, 10000);

    let req = http.get(option, (res) => {
      let xml = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        xml += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', () => {

        // add clearTimeout() here
        clearTimeout(timer);
        resolve(xml);
      });
    }).on('error', (err) => {

      // add clearTimeout() here
      clearTimeout(timer);
      reject(errMessage);
    });
  });
};
```